# Minimizing the Display in LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl, display

I am working on a game that uses **LWJGL**, and I need a way to minimize the Display with a method. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yeah, you could use a real language like C# and OpenTK. (Tongue in cheek). To answer your question though, you would need to embed the opengl instance into a JFrame and then minimize the JFrame instead. As far as I'm aware(been years since I last used Java/Lwjgl), there is not a way to do this to the static Display class itself.

Comment: By the way, this has already been asked, and they embed it into a JFrame, as I said. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677891/lwjgl-minimize-maximize-display

Comment: @Krythic even though the question has been asked before it still never got answered

Comment: @SemperAmbroscus I never said it did.

Comment: @Krythic then saying that the question has been asked before is irrelevant if it never had an answer in the first place

Comment: @SemperAmbroscus See, funny thing is, it really was answered though. You embed it into a JFrame and set the window state to iconified.

Comment: @Krythic See funny thing is, the question wasn't answered.

Comment: @Krythic Thanks this worked! Go ahead and leave an answer and ill give you the points.

Comment: @SemperAmbroscus Why are you trying to argue such an insignificant semantic? The question was answered; someone was helped.

Comment: @Krythic er, the question you linked was never answered, that's a fact. Why are you arguing otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to embed the LWJGL into a JPanel, Canvas, or something of the like. Doing this will allow you full control of the way your OpenGL layer is resized, etc. You can even have your own little "OpenGL controls" if you want to start getting fancy with it. [here](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/Using_a_Resizeable_AWT_Frame_with_LWJGL) and [here](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/Basic_LWJGL_Applet) are two good examples. The vital part of it is quite simply:

```
Display.setParent(myAwtOrSwingControl);
```

After this you can set:

```
myFrame.setState ( Frame.ICONIFIED );
```

To achieve the minimization that you're looking for.